# Why is my account still not deleted?

Tags: support

I've lost the fun in this site since the "back-it-up" policy was adopted and has started to become arbitrarily enforced (or not enforced). I could just leave it alone, but I'm not very disciplined about social media use. So, in order to prevent myself from writing another answer and have it deleted, I decided to delete my account two days ago.

I was surprised to see that this needs to be approved by someone else (and btw. wondering how compliant this is with the EU data protection regulation).

I was more surprised to see how long this takes. A minute ago, my profile page said the deletion was scheduled "yesterday". Now it doesn't mention the deletion at all anymore.

What can I do to expedite the process?

Note that I would really like to keep my other SE accounts.

Comment: It does still mention that it was scheduled for deletion 2 days ago, it just only shows up on your main site account, not the meta site. I am sorry for the delay. From what I understand, there are some complexities in deleting high-reputation user accounts and that requires manual staff intervention before actually deleting it. When the CM staff gets a bit backlogged, it can take a little longer than normal.

Answer (score 3):

Your account will be deleted when a community manager will take a look at it and approve the deletion. Sometimes, it takes more than 24 hours. Keep patience! There are a few things that need to be taken care of.

Anyway, we're sorry to see you go.

> What can I do to expedite the process? Note that I would really like to keep my other SE accounts.

There is nothing else you have to do. CMs will take care of it. And your IPS account will be deleted only unless you have chosen to delete any other SE account.

Comment: It's not a script, actually. One of the CMs reviews it and manually deletes the account for users with above a certain level of participation in a site.